# Saving Mutiple image path to the Database

Tags: php, mysql, image, laravel, image-uploading

I've been having a hard time researching how to save a group of image in my database in one upload. What I am thinking about is how will a group of addresses of image can be saved in one row? How can I fetch data if I will about to show it on my views? Should I change my fields data type on my database?  Here is my current code on saving 1 image.

```
   if(Input::hasFile('imgchick'))
    {

    $file = Input::file('imgchick');
    $img = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 240);
    $lgimg = Image::make($file);
    $name = time().'-'.'chicken.jpg';

    $img->save('images/chickens/thumbs/'.$name,30);

    $lgimg->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $lgimg->save('images/chickens/'.$name,60);

    $farm->img_loc=$name;
    }


    $farm->save();
```

Comment: It is usually done that you have 2 tables for it - one for group e.g. `image_group` and second for images `images`. In the `image_group` there are columns like `group_id | ...` and in the `images` there are columns like `image_id | group_id | source_name | ...`. One group has many images which you could simply fetch by `group_id` column.

Comment: if you really don't like another table, you can put them in one column by a nicely defined separator.Then make a parser for you to reverse.

Comment: wow, thats a good point, but I am not that good in php, dunno how to define a separator and make a parser

Comment: what you mean is we will be breaking a string data?